# How to configure netplan in Ubuntu 18.04 for DHCP and Static Routes

Tags: netplan

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 with 2 NICs.
Each NIC is attached to a different network.
My current configuration looks like:

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.3.1.102/24]
      gateway4: 10.3.1.20
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 10.3.1.5]
    eth1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.127.112.140, 10.126.11.1]
      routes:
        - to: 10.127.113.0/24
          via: 10.127.113.254
          metric: 100
        - to: 10.127.112.0/24
          via: 10.127.113.254
          metric: 100
```

However, with this configration eth1 fails to get an IP.
If I modify this to be:

```
eth1:
  dhcp4: no
  dhcp6: no
  addresses: [10.127.113.253/24]
  nameservers:
    addresses: [10.127.112.140, 10.126.11.1]
  routes:
    - to: 10.127.113.0/24
      via: 10.127.113.254
      metric: 100
    - to: 10.127.112.0/24
      via: 10.127.113.254
      metric: 100
```

Then I get an IP and routing as expected.
However, eth1 needs to be dhcp.  Any ideas on how to configure eth1 to be both dhcp AND have static routes in netplan?

Comment: I don't know much about networking but I always thought an interface can't have static and dynamic IP at the same time. And if dynamic with DHCP it must have a DHCP server in the network giving the IP.

Comment: also i thought it was `dhcp4: true` not `yes`

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: There is nothing in DHCP that would inherently prevent additional static addresses and/or routes from being added. If the OS tools don't let you do that, then it's only an artificial restriction.

Comment: Config in Ubuntu16.04 that works:  # The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.3.1.107
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.3.1.20
        network 10.3.1.0
        broadcast 10.3.1.255
        dns-nameservers 10.3.1.5 8.8.8.8
        up route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.3.1.20
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
        dns-nameservers 10.127.112.140 10.126.11.1
        up route add -net 10.127.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.127.113.254
        up route add -net 10.126.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.127.113.254

Comment: According to http://yaml.org/type/bool.html the acceptable values are y/n, yes/no, true/false and on/off, written either with all lowercase, with an Initial Capital, or with ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try ( add "on-link: true" )

```
eth1:
  dhcp4: yes
  dhcp6: no
  nameservers:
    addresses: [10.127.112.140, 10.126.11.1]
  routes:
    - to: 10.127.113.0/24
      via: 10.127.113.254
      metric: 100
      on-link: true
    - to: 10.127.112.0/24
      via: 10.127.113.254
      metric: 100
      on-link: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this netplan config if you using static:

```
    network:
      ethernets:
        ens18:
          dhcp4: false
          addresses: [10.0.15.122/24] # replace with your ip  
          gateway4: 10.0.15.1 # replace with your gateway
          nameservers:
            addresses:
            -10.2.1.2 # replace with yours
      version:2

sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SU. Unfortunately this does not answer the question. As it happens this is the exact opposite to what's wanted. The OP wants `eth1` interface get a dynamic IP address from DHCP server, but have static routes to certain destinations.